# JUnit Test though for loop

Tags: java, junit

I want create a test which loops though several test in a single test 
Lets say,

```
Test1 t1 = new Test1();
Test2 t2 = new Test2();
Test3 t3 = new Test3();
```

I want use a for loop which should run through this three test file to generate some test like this.

```
for (String string : Test) {
    test1.upload();
    test2.import();
}
```

Comment: What *specifically* are you testing? That each `TestN` function is called? Stub those out and set expectations on the calls.

Comment: lets say Test1 has different file format to test and test2 has some item to test. I want to make my test redundant and scalable..  Is it a better approach to test all the test from those two class to call from a main class ?

Comment: Each `TestN` class should be unit tested *on its own*. A test that uses multiple `TestN` classes shouldn't *re*-test `TestN`, rather you should test that the `TestN` methods are being called.

Comment: *I want create a test which loops though several test in a single test* this is a bit confusing, please use different names for concepts on different levels.

Comment: Are you after [parametrized tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests)?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to have a look at the `Parameterized` test runner in JUnit. You can use it this way: create an interface that all your `Test` classes implement. Your `@Parameters` method then returns a list of these objects.